# Move a sprite in a sine wave along different angles

Tags: mathematics, graphics

I understand this piece of code

`Enemy.position.Y = StartPosition.Y + (-(float)Math.Cos(position.X / 100) * 100);`

However it only works along the X axis. What I want to be able to do is move it along an arbitrary axis; Set an angle as the x axis.
How would I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question but here goes:

I think you want the sprite to wave over an angle back and forth:
Not this is pseudocode (as you didn't state the language):

```
t=(t+wavespeed)%TwoPi;
a = Sin(t)*amplitude;  
Position.X=StartPosition.X + Cos(angle) * a;
Position.Y=StartPosition.Y + Sin(angle) * a;
```

`t` controls the waving motion; the `wavespeed` variable is a small value like `0.01` (note that it should slowly range from 0 to TwoPi). `amplitude` is the maximum you want your sprite to move, `a` is calculated as the amplitude for that frame. `angle` is the angle of the axis you want your sprite to wave along.